# How to install a python module from Github with no root access?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, setuptools

I've read several article but I've had no luck as my situation conflicts with one or more freedoms that others have. This is my situation.

- I've no access to `root`.
- I'm just a user with access to python. No `sudo`.
- `python 2.x.x` is pre-installed
- `pip` is not pre-installed.
- `apt-get` requires root
  privileges.

**My goal** is to install a simple module called [Guessit](https://github.com/guessit-io/guessit) from Github for my `foo.py` project. The installation for it is given by `pip` so that option is ruled out. I tried to manually install as per https://github.com/guessit-io/guessit/blob/master/docs/sources.rst. I downloaded the zip file, extracted it and ran

```
python setup.py install
```

It gives me the following error

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
>     from setuptools import setup, find_packages
> ImportError: No module named setuptool
> ```

So, at this point I reckoned I needed `setuptools` module and hence downloaded https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py and tried to install it as per https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools by running

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
```

Again, it was a failure with an error like this:

> ```
> Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-24.0.0.zip
> Extracting in /tmp/tmplNW7fe
> Now working in /tmp/tmplNW7fe/setuptools-24.0.0
> Installing Setuptools
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
>     exec(init_file.read(), command_ns)
>   File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
>   File "/tmp/tmplNW7fe/setuptools-24.0.0/setuptools/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
>     from setuptools.extension import Extension
>   File "/tmp/tmplNW7fe/setuptools-24.0.0/setuptools/extension.py", line 11, in <module>
>     from . import msvc
>   File "/tmp/tmplNW7fe/setuptools-24.0.0/setuptools/msvc.py", line 244, in <module>
>     class PlatformInfo:
>   File "/tmp/tmplNW7fe/setuptools-24.0.0/setuptools/msvc.py", line 253, in PlatformInfo
>     current_cpu = safe_env['processor_architecture'].lower()
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
>     raise KeyError(key)
> KeyError: 'processor_architecture'
> Something went wrong during the installation.
> See the error message above.
> ```

Now, I'm guessing there is a match problem with the architecture of that setup and on my machine.

At this point, I'm not even sure if what I'm doing is right anymore. For whatever its worth, this is my the computer achitecture using `uname -a`

> ```
> Linux sl04.cmi.ac.in 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:41 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might be a little drastic, but given how tangled up you're getting, it might be the easiest way out: Install a minimal "anaconda scientific python" distribution (i.e. no packages, just the package manager and a minimal environment). It doesn't require root access and it comes with all the goodies like `pip`.

Comment: That is way off the track~

Comment: You can build the latest Python from source.

Comment: Isn't that a bit of an overkill too?

Comment: I think @notorious is making fun of my suggestion. I agree, it's a pretty blunt solution (that's why it's a comment, not an answer). But if you're failing to even install an installer, you have your work cut out for you.

Comment: Try `get-pip.py --user` https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python - --user`

Comment: What exactly is the version of Python you have?

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem in setuptools 24.0.0 (released today). I assume it will be fixed soon. Meanwhile, downgrade to 23.1 and reinstall the desired package.

Answer (score 1):

from your description it sounds like you could install `setuptools` in a user-local path to get over your first hurdle.

see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#installation-instructions

---

but really in a situation like the OP, you would bootstrap `pip`:

- download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
- run: `$ python get-pip.py`  (this will take care of installing setuptools for you)

then:

- `pip install virtualenv`

then use an activated virtualenv as a place to install your module.

This would keep your module or other dependencies apart from system packages, and doesn't require special privleges.

Comment: Be careful with this - you're replacing the system version of the package with your own.  Now you're assuming all responsibility for maintaining it!

Comment: @XiongChiamiov, not replacing it, but shadowing it locally.  I updated my answer with better explanation.